# What does "NOTE: A regression through the origin is fitted!" mean?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I'm using the plottol function in the tolerance package of R and getting an error / warning after my plot is generated that say "NOTE: A regression through the origin is fitted!"

I've googled it and come up with nothing and I don't know where to start with trying to figure out what it's warning me about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It in general indicates that a model is fitted whereby the intercept term is forced to be zero (in other words the model has no intercept).  The intercept in a model of `y ~ x` is the expectation of `y` when `x` is equal to 0. By setting the intercept to 0 we are explicitly stating that the expectation of `y` is 0 when `x` is 0. In other words, the straight line fitted to `y ~ x` passes through the point (0,0), i.e. the origin.

If you want a less general explanation (more tailored to your specific example) you'll need to provide more details on which of the many functions in **tolerance** you are using, e.g. via a reproducible example.